# How to change ControlTab title and icon by site browsed

Tags: c#

I want to make a browser în c# using Cefsharp And default ControlTab.
I done the job with the browser butt idk how to change ControlTab title by accessed site from Cefsharp to get title and icon of these.

Can anyone help me, plase?

Cheers.

The code :

```
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
        SetFormTitle(null);


    } 

    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        // Initialize cef with the provided settings
        if (Cef.IsInitialized == false)
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
        // Create a browser component
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
        // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void SetFormTitle(string tabName)
    {

     this.Text = tabName + " leoi ";

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have so far?

Comment: Sure, I added the code!

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Title`, in your `Form_Load` event, add:

```cs
Browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChange;
```

This will then call an `OnBrowserTitleChange` function:

```cs
private void OnBrowserTitleChange(object sender, TitleChange eventargs e) 
{ 
    // Put your code here, or Google it.  
}
```